# la funcion de java script me cancela otra funcion

Tags: javascript

"un ojo experimentado que ayude este novato"
tengo el siguiente codigo en mi archivo externo de j.s

```
const almac = document.querySelector('.almac');
almac.addEventListener('click',function(){
document.getElementById('barra').classList.toggle('active'); 
});


function writing(str){
let arrFromStr = str.split('');
let i = 0;
let printStr = setInterval(function(){
document.body.style.fontSize = '30px';
document.body.innerHTML += arrFromStr[i];
i++;
if (i === arrFromStr.length){
clearInterval(printStr);
}
},300);
};
writing('Me como el mundo con JS');
```

el primer bloque es una sidebar que se activa y desactiva

el segundo es una funcion que emula un fragmento de codigo escrito con maquina de escribir ....

pero el segundo bloque pareciera que me desactivara el primero pues el boton de hamburguesa deja de responder

que puede ser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se como explicarte el problema, pero puedo darte la solución, solo no escribas directamente en body, mejor en un campo definido, de esta manera debería funcionar

```
function writing(str){
let arrFromStr = str.split('');
let i = 0;
let printStr = setInterval(function(){
document.body.style.fontSize = '30px';
//Ahora el texto se escribira en un párrafo con clase "text"
document.querySelector('.text').innerHTML += arrFromStr[i];;
i++;
if (i === arrFromStr.length){
clearInterval(printStr);
}
},300);
};
writing('Me como el mundo con JS');
```

Y aqui el HTML

```
<p class="text"></p>
```

Comment: ok querido Pacman lo intentare y te comento

Comment: Apartir de hoy eres my Master aunque aun no sepa el porque  del error ... Me ayudaste a resolverlo  Gracias ... 

     Sabes serviría a la comunidad si explicas el porque de este error, tranquilo que nos esforzaremos en entender  tu explicación

Comment: Gracias :D, podrias ayudarme marcando la respuesta como correcta c:, investigare el porque del error.